# Heap dump in visualvm glassfish

Tags: monitoring, glassfish-4, visualvm, jvisualvm, heap-dump

I have a webservice on amazon ec2 running on glassfish 4 server, I tried to connect visualvm to the server but it were impossible, so I followed this tutorial (http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/remote-use-of-visualvm-with-xming/), I installed the plugin glassfish in the server jvisualvm, and now I can monitor glassfish, but i cant do a heap dump to see my application use of memory detailled.
How can I do?

[image: Error trying heap dump]

Comment: Did you try right-clicking the application in the Applications window and selecting Heap Dump?

Comment: I edit my question and post a screenshot. I try right-clicking glassfish on the left menu, and selecting heap dump, but it show me the error that you can see on the screen-shot.

Comment: you might not have privileges to take the heap dump.  Are you running the process as a privileged user?

Comment: Yes I run it as sudo

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `jmap` tool in the JDK to create an HPROF format heapdump:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html

As an example, with the PID of your GlassFish in the screenshot above, the command would be as follows:

```
jmap -dump:file=/path/to/my/dumpfile.hprof 1376
```

You could also use `jps` to find the process ID:

```
jps -v
```

The `-v` flag makes the output verbose, giving you more information to tell which process is the right one.